# multiple spawns in expected scripts

Tags: ssh, expect

I started learning expected script newly. could  you please make to understand what is happening in the following code.

there is a file called one.exp with the code as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/expect  
global slawn_id  
set timeout -1  
spawn NoPktdrop.exp  
spawn perl NoPktDrop.pl NoPktDrop
spawn NoPktDrop.exp  
spawn perl NoPktDrop.pl  NoPktDrop  
interact   

the code of NoPktdrop.exp is as follows.

#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1  
while {1} {  
spawn telnet  server  
sleep 1  
expect {  
    "Escape character" {  
            send "\r"  
            expect "SP*>*%"  

            break
       } 
       "Connection refused" {  
                break  

        }  
    }  
}
           send "\x1D"  
            expect "telnet> "  
             send "q\r"  
            expect "Connection*%"
```

and perl script has some code.

I need to execute first expect script then once it has generated the NoPktDroplog , the log needs to be given to the perl script for some checks. that I need to repeat it for some reasons. But I am seeing the expected scripts are not getting executed . only the perl scripting is executed. please let me know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
spawn NoPktdrop.exp  
spawn perl NoPktDrop.pl NoPktDrop
spawn NoPktDrop.exp  
spawn perl NoPktDrop.pl  NoPktDrop  
interact
```

changed the above  code as below . then it worked. not sure about the reason. Thanks.

```
spawn NoPktdrop.exp  
expect eop
spawn perl NoPktDrop.pl NoPktDrop
expect eop
spawn NoPktDrop.exp 
expect eop 
spawn perl NoPktDrop.pl  NoPktDrop  
expect eop
```

Comment: You want `eof` not `eop` -- expecing the EOF will have you wait (up to the timeout value) for the spawned process to complete.

Comment: thanks glenn for  providing the reason. could you also mention why I need to remove the interact. I am not able to get where  exactly interact  is required.